# How to output a dictionary I made in a class in Python pandas

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm getting back into Python and am currently working on code that takes the name and associated numbers for logins from various points from an excel sheet, sums up the numbers, and then adds the name to a dictionary with an associated value of "low", "medium", or "high".  I've been able to get the code to work in function form, and am currently putting it into a class:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import sys

class aggregateActivity:

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = "path to excel file"
        self.s = "name of excel worksheet"
        self.activityAssociation = {}

        dfs = pd.read_excel(self.l, self.s, usecols=[1,2,3])
        numberOfLogins = dfs.sum(axis=1)
        activity = {}

        for index, row in dfs.iterrows():
            activity[row[0]]=numberOfLogins[index]

        for key in activity:
            if activity.get(key) < 100:
                activityAssociation[key] = "Low"
            if activity.get(key) >= 100 and activity.get(key) < 200:
                activityAssociation[key] = "Medium"
            if activity.get(key) >= 200:
                activityAssociation[key] = "High"

x = aggregateActivity()

x.activityAssociation
```

The issue here is that when I run the code, jupyter outputs an empty dictionary:

```
{}
```

I've checked to see if the dictionary actually has contents added to it be appending `print(activityAssociation)` to the end of the class, and can confirm that it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `self.` which is causing python to create a new `activityAssociation` **local** variable

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import sys

class aggregateActivity:

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = "path to excel file"
        self.s = "name of excel worksheet"
        self.activityAssociation = {}

        dfs = pd.read_excel(self.l, self.s, usecols=[1,2,3])
        numberOfLogins = dfs.sum(axis=1)
        activity = {}

        for index, row in dfs.iterrows():
            activity[row[0]]=numberOfLogins[index]

        for key in activity:
            if activity.get(key) < 100:
                self.activityAssociation[key] = "Low"
            if activity.get(key) >= 100 and activity.get(key) < 200:
                self.activityAssociation[key] = "Medium"
            if activity.get(key) >= 200:
                self.activityAssociation[key] = "High"

x = aggregateActivity()

x.activityAssociation
```

Comment: That did it.  Thank you very much.